# Error al poner más de tres "include" en php

Tags: php

No puedo poner más de 3 include en un index, pongo más de 3 y se me oculta el header o el footer que están con require, si alguien sabe alguna solución se lo agradecería. Aquí esta la parte donde tengo problemas.

```
<?php require_once("header.php");?>
<?php require_once("menu.php");?>

<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-events" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-events-tab">
            <?php include_once'events-and-closing.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-boytoys" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-boytoys-tab">
            <?php include_once'boy-toys-for-sale.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-americanshotguns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-americanshotguns-tab">
            <?php include_once'american-shotguns.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-englishshotguns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-englishshotguns-tab"> 
            <?php include_once'english-shotguns.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-europeanshotguns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-europeanshotguns-tab">
            <?php include_once'european-shotguns.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-caesarfabarm" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-caesarfabarm-tab">
            <?php include_once'caesar-fabarm.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-rifles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-rifles-tab">
            <?php include_once'rifles.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-doublerifles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-doublerifles-tab">
            <?php include_once'double-rifles.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-collectiblefirearms" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-collectiblefirearms-tab">
            <?php include_once'collectible-firearms.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-handguns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-handguns-tab">
            <?php include_once'hand-guns.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-artwork" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-artwork-tab">
            <?php include_once'art-work.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="v-pills-sportingcollectibles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-sportingcollectibles-tab">
            <?php include_once'sporting-collectibles.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-vintageammocases" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-vintageammocases-tab">
            <?php include_once'vintage-ammo-cases.php';?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-contact-tab">
            <?php include_once'contact-us.php';?>
</div>

<?php require_once('footer.php')?>
```

Las rutas están bien y funcionan si pongo include'./ruta'; dos veces, pero si lo pongo tres se esconde el footer o los otros div, ya probé con include, include_once, require, require_once.

Comment: Edita y coloca el código relevante además explica de mejor manera tu problema

Comment: usa `include_once` y/o `require_once`  de esa manera los incluye o requiere sólo una vez, como dice @Aprendiz con código sería mas facil ver el por qué falla.

Comment: ya le agregué el código, he probado varias cosas y nada me funciona.

Comment: Mira a ver si el problema se te produce cuando llamas a un `include` en concreto. Es posible que dentro de este tengas algo raro en el **HTML** (alguna etiqueta sin cerrar, me atrevería a decir) que te esté ocasionando ese mal funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo lo que comentas apuntaría a que tienes algún **error 500** en algunos de los archivos incluidos o las rutas no están correctas.

Puedes probar a debuguear incluyendo las siguientes líneas al comienzo del archivo:

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! hice eso y encontré los errores que no me dejaban ver los include en el index.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido de utilidad. Recuerda borrar esas líneas cuando hayas terminado de debuguear. Un saludo!